# Website background audio not playing instantly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I would like to play background music as soon as my homepage loads. This happens but for one reason or another it only plays after 8 - 10 seconds.

Also i can't seem to lower the volume. This is my code:

```
<audio src="music/ItaloBrothers - Summer Air (Official Video).mp3" id="my_audio" loop="loop"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
    console.log('your audio is started just now');
  }, 1000)
</script>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_autoplay

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a script, just add `autoplay` property to your audio tag.
If you want this in a script, add this in the `document.onload()` event.

Comment: It still plays after 5 - 8 seconds when I put in the autoplay and remove the script.

Comment: Maybe your page is cahced. Try to clear the cache.

Comment: The browser requires an user interaction before it will allow any audio.

Answer (score 1):

`<audio src="music/ItaloBrothers - Summer Air (Official Video).mp3" id="my_audio" loop="loop"  autoplay controls></audio>`

You have to add "controls" to get the audio controlling buttons and use "autoplay" to autoplay the audio when the site has loaded. \

**Chrome does not suport autoplay**

Answer (score 0):

Add `autoplay` like this:

```
<audio autoplay src="music/ItaloBrothers - Summer Air (Official Video).mp3" id="my_audio" loop="loop"></audio>
```

Or try this:

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="music/ItaloBrothers - Summer Air (Official Video).mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Didn't fix the problem :(

Comment: @VinSe1337 Don't forget to remove the script tag and clear the cache.

Comment: I removed the script and deleted my cache but it didn't help.

Comment: @VinSe1337 I updated the answer, can you try now.

Comment: Dont forget to warn all your visitors that your audio starts right away, you might be the last site on the internet who does this.